# Prompting an IPhone user to add a web page developed in Asp.Net MVC to home screen

Tags: ios, iphone, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have designed and developed a web application using Asp.Net MVC and added some meta tags to make if Look like an IPhone App. 
Now How do I prompt a user to add that page on home screen whenever I open the App for the first time on an IPhone instead of adding it manually from option available on the IPhone.

I have added the  following meta tags to my head tag

```
<head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon"
          href="~/Images/icon.png" />
          <link rel="mobile-touch-icon"
          href="~/Images/icon.png" />

        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          href="~/Images/startup.png" />


         <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>
<body>

     <script>
            if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
                if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
                    initialize();
                }else{
                    document.write('<p>Tap the + button and choose "Add to Home Screen"</p>');
                }
            }
        </script>

</body>
```

How can I prompt a user to add the page on the Home Screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this yourself, please take a look at [Add to home screen script](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) by Cubic. Easy to config and yes works across wide range of i-devices.